# How to write webpack external for module subdirectory

Tags: webpack, subdirectory, react-intl, externals

I am trying to add all files from module subdirectory to Webpack externals.
Especially data of [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) locale files.

I am tryng to specify a path to the locale files with a regexp in a webpack config, but it does't work:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: [
   /react-intl\/locale-data\/.*/,
   // ...
  ]
};
```

I am loading those files dynamically, is there a problem?

```
const localeData = require(`react-intl/locale-data/${language.getLocale()}`);
```

Every dependency is correctly externalized, except those locale files:
[Webpack bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IBTN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like

```
const localeData = require(`react-intl/locale-data/en`);
```

if you specify not a dynamic way, then it works as you expected.

I've been using a different way to avoid this problem as below and load dynamically.

```
// Choose the locales that we want to include for react-intl
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/react-intl[\/\\]locale-data$/, /en|ja|id|es/),
```

Comment: Thanks @banyan. Meanwhile, I've also got to this solution. While, I think the dynamic loading is the issue here, I am marking your answer as accepting.